# Mantaflow Fluids Not Working

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have tried many times to create a simple Mantaflow fluid simulation in Blender 2.82, but it almost never works.

Edit: I tried saving the file, and baking the whole simulation. I also fiddled around with almost every setting that I could think of, and it is still not working.

Edit #2: None of the physics with Mantaflow are working :/

There is one [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdUWqkqcxzw) that sometimes works but whenever I do it on my own (domain and inflow objects) it doesn't work.

Comment: have you saved your file, and baked the simulation?

Comment: I baked it, I didn't save the file, I'll try that.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried both saving, and baking everything, I also made sure the bake folder was writable and readable from this user, (I'm on the admin account) but it still isn't working. It seems like something is calculating when baking but then no particles show up. Here is my .blend file: https://filebin.net/iqll615civiuunq8/Fluid_Test__Not_working_.zip?t=s9a2l8w5

Comment: Hey! I think I may have figured it out. All fluid inflow objects must be enclosed by a domain? I don't know why though....

Comment: yep, the simulation is all happening inside the domain

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the circle with a full 3d object. mantaFlow can only use 3d objects in the full release. If this still doesn't work, try an ico-sphere as a last resort method.

Answer (score 0):

Is your inflow object inside of the domain? That is a problem I ran into, my inflow was to big and was not fully inside of the domain.